# VBA Syntax for Reference of a cell instead of cell value

Tags: vba, reference

I want the VBA syntax for the reference of a cell instead of the value.

I know that

`Workbook().Worksheet().Cell().Value` returns the value of the cell.

I want to know the cell reference, something like this `='[Vba Source Test.xlsx]Source'!$B$8`

I tried using:

```
workbook().worksheet().cell().address
```

but it only returns the `$B$8` part.

I will be using it in a code like this.

```
Workbook(Master).Worksheet(Summary).range(a1).value =  
workbook(Source).Worksheet(Data).cell(2,8).address
```

Thank you again for whoever can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the object names & the range address, with the appropriate separators:

`"='["Workbook(Source).Name & "]" & Worksheet(Data).Name & "'" & Cells(2,8).Address`

Because what you are doing is assigning a `String` value to the cell's `Formula`, I think this should work (but I have not tested, so there may be typo):

```
Dim myFormula as String
myFormula = "='["Workbook(Source).Name & "]" & Worksheet(Data).Name & "'!" & Cells(2,8).Address

Workbook(Master).Worksheet(Summary).range(a1).Formula = myFormula
```

You may be able to omit the Workbook `Name` from this, I'm pretty sure that the Workbook name is automatic as long as you specify the worksheet belonging to an open workbook. If the file is not open when you insert the formula, you will have to include the workbook name.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'm going to fiddle with the formula. Kinda confusing since I set my workbooks to certain names. You would think excel has a built in property for this situation.

Comment: Got it to work. the missing part was "!" 

WSMaster.Cells(master2, master1).Value = "='[" & sourcetext & "]" & sourcetext1 & "'" & "!" & address1